# How to get the last characters of formatted output when snprintf returns more than its size argument?

Tags: c, printf

I have a buffer that is 65536 characters long. I need to print formatted output to the buffer. Problem is: If the formatted output size turns out to be bigger than 65535, I would like to have the last characters of it in the buffer, discarding the first ones, and not the remaining ones, as `snprintf` does.

I thought about implementing the `snprintf` logic, but starting from the end of the string instead of the beginning.

Is there any easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: What are you doing that could possibly need more than 65535 characters in a single formatted output?

Comment: Consider dynamically allocating if you're unsure of how much storage you need. If you guess wrong you can reallocate.

Comment: Can you show an example of the format string? I assume it must be printing a potentially long string. So you could split it up into separate calls, for everything before the string, and everything after the string. Then you add the lengths of each of these to the length of the string, and see whether it's longer than 65535.

Comment: @Barmar I'm writing my own terminal. I haven't thought about examples of my program where that could happen. Currently, I'm writing a function that sends data to be printed to the terminal, and can be formatted. What if the buffer size was smaller? _"Declare bigger buffers"_ can't be a solution to every instance of this problem :P

Comment: @Barmar By doing that, you're formatting the entirety of the data anyway. At that point you might as well do it the easy way and just use something like `asprintf()` to start.

Comment: Why are you using `sprintf()` when implementing a terminal? It should just output everything it's given, it doesn't need to format it, and shouldn't cut anything off. This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @Barmar Well, terminals do have control characters...

Comment: @Barmar When you `cat` a huge file in the shell, its output is not there forever. It starts discarding lines of output after the 8192nd. I'm using `snprintf` for printing given error messages to the terminal.

Comment: You're talking about the scrollback buffer? That wouldn't be implemented with `sprintf()`.

Comment: You append to the buffer when output happens. When the buffer reaches its limit, you remove characters from the beginning and add to the end. A circular buffer data structure would be helpful.

Comment: @Barmar I'm aware of it, I'm using a circular buffer. My concern is that if a formatted output is longer than the buffer size (65536), any user of a terminal would expect to see the beginning of the message being discarded, and not the end of it.

Comment: What about `open_memstream` and doing `fprintf` to that?

Comment: @YuriJ That will happen naturally. Every time you copy from the stream to the circular buffer, the beginning will be discarded.

Comment: Be aware `fprintf()`  has an _environmental_ limit.  That limit is _at least_ 4095.  Using `fprintf()` for this task is not a robust approach.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int snprintfEnd(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list ap1, ap2;

  va_start(ap1, format);
  va_copy(ap2, ap1);

  /* get length of all */
  int sz = vsnprintf(0, 0, format, ap2);

  va_end(ap2);

  /* get all */
  char * all = malloc(sz + 1);

  vsprintf(all, format, ap1);
  va_end(ap1);

  /* copy the expected part */
  int r;

  if (sz < size) {
    strcpy(str, all);
    r = sz;
  }
  else {
    strcpy(str, all + sz - size);
    r = size;
  }

  free(all);
  return r;
}

int main()
{
  char s[6];

  int ln = snprintfEnd(s, 5, "%d %d %d", 1, 234, 567);

  printf("%d : '%s'\n", ln, s);

  return 0;
}
```

Execution :

```
5 : '4 567'
```

Comment: `size_t size` in `snprintfEnd()` is begin used as the max string _length_ (without the _null character_).  IMO, `snprintfEnd(s, 5, "%d %d %d", 1, 234, 567)` should use `size` as the size of the destination allowed including the _null character_ and then `s` becomes    `"4 56"` that needs 5 `char`.

Comment: Such excessively long uses of `*print()` are prone to _Environmental limits_. C11 §7.21.6.1 15.  This may be a case where "fprintf function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a **negative value if an output or encoding error occurred**.".  So checking for that from `int sz = vsnprintf()` would be prudent.